# Comparing an array to its mirror

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Okay so I have a method that needs to take in an array full of `ints`, then check it against it's mirror to see what the largest mirror is that it matches to. So for example I have array `[7, 1, 2, 9, 7, 2, 1]`, the largest array that it can match is 2, being matched at `[1, 2]`.

Right now I have it broken into 3 methods. One that accepts the array, another that reverses the array and returns it (`mirrorArray`). and the 3rd being counting the size of the array that matches(`groupCount`). Here is what I have so far:

```
public int maxMirror(int[] nums) {
  int[] revArray = mirrorArray(nums);

  return groupCount(nums, revArray);
}

private int[] mirrorArray(int[] nums) {
  int[] newArray = new int[nums.length];

  for (int i = nums.length-1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
    newArray[j] = nums[i];
  }

  return newArray;
}

private int groupCount(int[] aFor, int[] bRev) {
  int maxCount = 0;
  int groupSize = 1;

  //get aFor value
  for (int i = 0; i < aFor.length; i++) {
    int[] tempA = Arrays.copyOfRange(aFor, 0, groupSize);

    //loop through bRev and check for matches
    for (int j = 0; j < bRev.length; j++) {
      int[] tempB = Arrays.copyOfRange(bRev, j, j+groupSize);

      if (Arrays.equals(tempA, tempB)) {
        maxCount = tempA.length;
      }
    }

    groupSize++;
  }
  return maxCount;
}
```

It is failing in the 3rd method somewhere (returning a 1 instead of a 2) and I'm stumped why the loops I have arnt returning what I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is it failing? To you get an Exception? Are the returned values wrong?

Comment: The values that are being returned are wrong. For example, if it runs through the array in above example, it is returning a 1, when it should be a 2.

Comment: When `groupCount` method is called what values are in `aFor` and `bRev`?

Comment: aFor is the forward array from what was originally passed in, bRev is the reverse of that. Being calculated in the `mirrorArray` method.

Comment: Check my answer, I solved the problem without allocating new arrays (massive performance gain!), I hope that helps you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright I was curious...

Here's the problem:

```
int[] tempA = Arrays.copyOfRange(aFor, 0, groupSize);
```

You are always comparing tempB to the first subArray of length `groupSize` of aFor.  Change that line to

```
int[] tempA = Arrays.copyOfRange(aFor, i, i + groupSize);
```

and it should work.

**EDIT** Keep the failure cases coming..  Seems an issue with the increment location of groupSize

```
   while (groupSize < aFor.length) {
      //get aFor value
      for (int i = 0; i < aFor.length; i++) {
        int[] tempA = Arrays.copyOfRange(aFor, i, i + groupSize);

        //loop through bRev and check for matches
        for (int j = 0; j < bRev.length; j++) {
          int[] tempB = Arrays.copyOfRange(bRev, j, j+groupSize);

          if (Arrays.equals(tempA, tempB)) {
            maxCount = groupSize;
          }
        }
      }
      groupSize++;
  }
```

This is not the most efficient, and it might be a fun exercise to optimize.  One starting approach would be to start groupSize at `aFor.length` and decrement.  As soon as `maxCount` is assigned, you can early return.

**Edit 2**

```
 int groupSize = aFor.length;
 while (groupSize >= 0) {
      //get aFor value
      for (int i = 0; i <= aFor.length - groupSize; i++) { // note this change
        int[] tempA = Arrays.copyOfRange(aFor, i, i + groupSize);

        //loop through bRev and check for matches
        for (int j = 0; j <= bRev.length - groupSize; j++) { // note this change
          int[] tempB = Arrays.copyOfRange(bRev, j, j+groupSize);

          if (Arrays.equals(tempA, tempB)) {
            return groupSize;
          }
        }
      }
      groupSize--;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

What was happening is that Arrays.copyOfRange was filling out of bounds numbers with zeroes.  I also added the early exit opt I mentioned earlier.  There are probably more optimizations that can be done

Comment: +1 had the same idea but i wasn't sure that the mirror of `aFor` is `bRev`

Comment: Yea I tried that earlier, when I add that I am still getting errors from some arrays. Example, array `[1,2,1,4]` returns a 2, when it should be 3.

Comment: This is so close. I changed the your while to `while (groupsize <= aFor.length)` because it wasn't going to the end of some arrays, but i am still getting errors :(. Example, `[1,2,3,8,9,3,2,1]` is returning 8, when it is suposed to be 3.

Comment: Feel like im being a pain but, this just presented more errors. (but different) on arrays like `[1, 2, 1, 4]` I will get 2 returned when 3 was suposed to be returned =[

Comment: Nevermind I got it! I changed the loops to `groupsize >= 0` & `i <= ..` & `j <= ..` and it all worked out! Thanks you've been such a great help !

Comment: Not a pain at all - I didn't regression test ;)  Glad you found the issue and I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your logic between `tempA` and `tempB` has issue:

In each iteration of first loop (orignal) you pick 0->groupSize set of values and compare exactly with all similar sizes sequence in reverse array, so first iteration is

```
Orignal array (aFor) : [7, 1, 2, 9, 7, 2, 1]
Reverse array (bRev) : [1, 2, 7, 9, 2, 1, 7]
Iteration-1:
tempA=> [7]
tempB=> [1],[2],[7]...
maxCount = 1; (in first iteration, multiple single value matche)

Iteration-2:
tempA=> [7,1]
tempB=> [1,2],[2,7]...
maxCount = 1; (no match of [7,1], maxCount continues from first iteration)
```

Similarly in all other iteration no sequence match would be found due to your input dataset.

> Now if you change your input to [7, 1, 2, 9, 7, 1, 7], **maxCount would be 2**
>
> And for input [7, 1, 2, 9, 2, 1, 7], **maxCount is 7**

But that's due to nature of your input and issue in your code.

The problem in code is outer loop (`aFor` loop) doesn't gets evaluated for each sequence set i.e. in iteration-2 you check only first set of size 2 ([7,1]) and further sets ([1,2],[2,9]..) are never compared so you always get maxCount=1 due to previous match.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this might seem irrelevant to the question, but I tried to make the tests without creating new arrays (inplace comparaison), I hope this helps:

```
public static int getMaxMirrorSub(int[] arr) {
    for (int eqLength = arr.length; eqLength >= 0; eqLength--) {
        for (int arrayStart = 0; arrayStart < arr.length; arrayStart++) {
            for (int mirrorStart = arr.length - 1; mirrorStart >= eqLength - 1; mirrorStart--) {
                int indexArray = arrayStart, indexMirror = mirrorStart;
                while(indexArray < arr.length 
                        && indexMirror >= 0 
                        && arr[indexArray] == arr[indexMirror]){

                    indexArray++; indexMirror--;
                }

                if (indexArray - arrayStart == eqLength)
                    return eqLength;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int maxMirror(int[] nums) {
  int[] reverse = null;
  int max = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
     for(int k = 0; k < nums.length; k++) {
        if(i > k) { 
          } else {
            reverse = reverseSection(nums, i, k);
            if(searchFor(reverse, nums)) {
               if(reverse.length > max) { max = reverse.length; }
            }
         }
     }
  }

  return max;
}

public int[] reverseSection(int[] nums, int begin, int end) {
   int[] nArray = new int[end - begin + 1];
   int numbs = end - begin;
   for(int i = begin; i <= end; i++) {
      nArray[numbs] = nums[i];
      numbs--;
   }
   return nArray;
}

public boolean searchFor(int[] reverse, int[] nums) {
    int index = 0;
    boolean check = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[i] == reverse[index]) {
            index++;

            if(index >= reverse.length) {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            index = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In addition to providing code, please also include some text to explain what your answer does and how it fixes the OP's question. This will help future readers with the same or a similar question use your answer.